# Ubuntu 20.04 apt-get update Release file not found

Tags: linux, apt, apt-get, ubuntu-20.04

Trying to run `sudo apt-get update` or even just `sudo apt update` results in the following output for me:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                              
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                        
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                              
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hvr/ghc/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.10/prod eoan InRelease                                                                         
Ign:8 https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/pcsc-lite.git focal InRelease                                         
Err:9 https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/pcsc-lite.git focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:648:2ffc:deb::211:202 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/pcsc-lite.git focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried clicking on the https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/pcsc-lite.git link and then shortening the url until anonscm.debian.org brought me to [this strange page](https://anonscm.debian.org/) which talked about how a certain debian service is discontinued. However, I'm a bit of a linux beginner and instead of going down a rabbit hole wherein I might further break my environment, I'd really appreciate some help with what to do about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT Yes. I am connected to the internet.**

[Notice how my internet is up yet the updater gives me the no connection message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14oBI.png)

**Second Edit: yes. I am connected and my livepatch is on**
[as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9CZq.png)

**Third edit** Somehow after closing the settings like in the second picture, the software updater decides to run. This is the same as if I had run `apt-get update` in the terminal, is it not? Yet why does it not work in the terminal?

[software updater appears to run?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdBxa.png)

Comment: There is an Icon on the left side of your screen (if a standard setup) that looks like a capital A .  That is the updater.  Click on that and if will tell you (a) if no internet (not likely) or (b) if you have logged in (more likely).

Comment: You're talking about the software updater? I already tried this. It says "failed to download repository information check your internet connection." But I am connected. I'm posting this comment on the internet on this same machine right now. What do you mean "logged in,"? To the wifi network? I am.

Comment: When you run it, there should be a Settings icon lower left. Click on Settings (Updater Settings). Click on Live Patch and make sure (a) it is ON and (b) there are no errors. If not logged in it will present an error.  I am logged in so there is no error in my display.

Comment: Also try Live Patch from here:  https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch

Comment: The live patch was already on and there appears to be no errors as I provide in the screenshot

Comment: For the error in your screenshot (I saw that once), try restarting the machine. That worked in my case.  Also try reinstalling Live Patch.

Comment: That didn't work either. Uninstalled then reinstalled live patch. I get their weird behavior where after the terminal command to update fails, as well as the software updater, after I close the software updater settings it runs the update check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have an (now) invalid URL as a repository.

Open a terminal and switch to root. (`sudo -i`)

Then do

```
cd /etc/apt/
grep -lris anonscm.debian.org
```

Then open the file that is printed with your favorite textedior
e.g. `nano /your/file/here.list`

Search for the line that goes something like

```
deb https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/pcsc-lite.git focal Release
```

Delete that line. Then save and exit

> in nano that would be `ctrl + X` > `y` > `<ENTER>`

then try `apt update && apt upgrade` again.

Comment: Thanks, that got it working.